# How do I root Android Lollipop developer preview?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, rooting, nexus-5, developer-preview

How can I best root the new Android Lollipop developer preview? Chainfire's original SuperSU binaries don't seem to work:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image: IMG: screenshot of issue]

> There is no SU binary installed, and SuperSU cannot install it. This is a problem!
>
> If you just upgraded to Android 4.3, you need to manually re-root - consult the relevant forums for your device!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the only officially supported devices for the developer preview are the Nexus 5 & Nexus 7 (2013).

Chainfire has issued updated [SuperSU binaries](http://download.chainfire.eu/supersu) that allow rooting, but the recently updated developer previews seem to have broken this, resulting in the SuperSU binaries not being recognised.

Fortunately, Chainfire has responded with a quick fix: [flashing a custom android kernel](https://plus.google.com/+Chainfire/posts/ZzXaU1W7Uzm).

Simply flash the modified kernel in fastboot then the SuperSU binaries zip and your device should be rooted.

**EDIT**: Some users have reported issues with the kernel Chainfire provided. Try flashing [this one](https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=95747613655047203) instead.